Finding the determinant of a matrix under given conditions
Let $x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4, x_5 > 0$ and $A = [a_{ij}]_{5 \times 5}$ be a matrix such that
$$
a_{ij} = 
\begin{cases}
|x_i - x_j|, & \text{if } i \neq j \\
x_i, & \text{if } i = j
\end{cases}
$$
If the following hold
$$
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
(x_1^2 - x_5 x_3)(x_2^2 - x_5 x_3) &\leq 0, \\
(x_2^2 - x_4 x_1)(x_3^2 - x_4 x_1) &\leq 0, \\
(x_3^2 - x_5 x_2)(x_4^2 - x_5 x_2) &\leq 0, \\
(x_4^2 - x_1 x_3)(x_5^2 - x_1 x_3) &\leq 0, \\
(x_5^2 - x_2 x_4)(x_1^2 - x_2 x_4) &\leq 0, 
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$
Find determinant $A$ given $x_3=3$.
Failed attempt
I noticed that the terms given in the inequality are themselves the product of two determinants i.e,
$$\det\begin{pmatrix}
x_1 & x_3 \\
x_5 & x_1
\end{pmatrix}
\cdot
\det\begin{pmatrix}
x_2 & x_3 \\
x_5 & x_2
\end{pmatrix}
\leq 0
$$
for the first inequality and so on.
After that, I tried solving the $5\times5$ determinant to see if I could apply what I showed before. But it didn't simplify to any desirable form.

You might find it helpful to begin with the assumption that $x_1 \leq x_2 \leq x_3 \leq x_4 \leq x_5$ in order to avoid the absolute values. Note that rearranging the $x_i$'s amounts to the application of a permutation similarity over the matrix

Setting $x_i = 3$ gives one possible solution which translates to a diagonal matrix. So $\det (A) = 243$ is a solution. I'm curious if there are other solutions.

@PandaScientist 243 is indeed the correct answer. But how do I prove this is the only answer? And is there any way to do this problem without trial and error?

@BenGrossmann I did what you told me, and it helped to some extent. But I'm still nowhere near the answer.

As a next step from Panda's approach, you might want to consider what happens if we change one $x_i$ at a time. For instance, consider $x_1 = \cdots = x_4 = 3$ and $x_5 > 3$

I have encountered a related problem before: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3807267/if-x-i2-x-i2x-i-1x-i12-x-i2x-i-1-leq-0-for-all-i-1-2-3-4-5?rq=1

This is just a variation on explaining Macavity's answer, but it might help if the idea of cyclic summing is not familiar. If you view the indices of the indeterminates as elements of $\mathbb Z/5\mathbb Z$ (so that $x_5$ is the same as $x_0$ and so forth), then the inequalities are given by
$$
\begin{split}
&(x_i^2-x_{i+2}x_{i+4})(x_{i+1}^2-x_{i+2}x_{i+4})\leq 0 \\
\iff& x_i^2x_{i+1}^2 +x_{i+2}^2x_{i+4}^2 \leq x_i^2x_{i+2}x_{i+4} + x_{i+1}^2x_{i+2}x_{i+4}
\end{split}
$$
where $i$ runs over $\mathbb Z/5\mathbb Z$.
Now considering the summing all of these inequalities. Every term contains at least one $x_i^2$, so lets consider those terms on each side which contain $x_1^2$: On the left-hand side we must have $1\in \{i,i+1,i+2,i+4\}$, so that $i\in \{0,1,2,4\}$ and hence we have $x_1^2(x_0^2+x_2^2+x_4^2+x_3^2)$ on the left-hand side. On the right-hand side $x_1^2$ occurs when $i=1$ or $i=0$ giving $x_1^2(x_3x_5+x_2x_4)$. Since the inequalities are preserves under translating the indices, the sum is therefore
$$
\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i\in \mathbb Z/5\mathbb Z} x_i^2(\sum_{j \neq i} x_j^2)\leq \sum_{i\in \mathbb Z/5\mathbb Z} x_i^2(x_{i+2}x_{i+4} + x_{i+1}x_{i+3})
$$
where we need the factor of $1/2$ on the left-hand side because each $x_k^2x_l^2$ is counted twice (once when $i=k$ and once when $i=l$). Equivalently,
$$
\tag{$\dagger$}
\sum_{i\in \mathbb Z/5\mathbb Z} x_i^2\left(\sum_{j=1}^4 x_{i+j}^2 \right)\leq 2\sum_{i \in \mathbb Z/5\mathbb Z} x_i^2(x_{i+2}x_{i+4}+x_{i+1}x_{i+3})
$$
But
$$
\sum_{j=1}^4 x_{i+j}^2-2x_{i+2}x_{i+4} -2x_{i+1}x_{i+3} = (x_{i+1}-x_{i+3})^2+(x_{i+2}-x_{i+4})^2\geq 0
$$
so the opposite equality to $\dagger$ also holds and the previous line makes it clear that equality happens only if $x_{i+1}=x_{i-2}$ and $x_{i+2}=x_{i-1}$ for all $i \in \mathbb Z/5\mathbb Z$, hence $x_i=x_j$ for all $i,j$ and the matrix is $x.I_5$ where $x$ is the common value of the $x_i$s. If this is $3$ then $\det(3.I_5)=3^5 = 243$.

I wasn't familiar with "cyclic sums" before, but your answer provided me with valuable insights on the topic. thank you!

Glad it helped!

Summing all the inequality conditions after expanding, one gets $$\sum_{cyc}(x_1^2x_2^2+x_3^2x_5^2) \leqslant \sum_{cyc}(x_1^2+x_2^2)x_3x_5$$
However by AM-GM, $\frac12(x_1^2x_3^2+x_5^2x_1^2) \geqslant x_1^2x_3x_5$, and cyclically summing several of those, we can write $$\sum_{cyc}(x_1^2x_2^2+x_3^2x_5^2) \geqslant \sum_{cyc}(x_1^2+x_2^2)x_3x_5$$
For both these to hold true, we must have $x_1=x_2=x_3=x_4=x_5=3$ (in this case), and then the determinant is trivial.

"..and cyclically summing several of those..."- can you pls show the sum. I'm unable to reach the final inequality

@rohit1729 you should be able to do the sum easily though you need to write out ten such AM-GMs. To clarify more, we should have the cycling sum $\frac12\sum x_1^2(x_3^2+x_5^2) \geqslant \sum x_1^2x_3x_5$ which leads to 5 terms in the RHS, and $\frac12\sum x_2^2(x_3^2+x_5^2) \geqslant \sum x_2^2x_3x_5$ should give 5 more terms to complete the RHS.  Let me know which term is missing or extra in any of the sides of the inequality when you sum it.
